# Staggered animation, using setTimeout, is choppy

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, settimeout

I'm animating three elements within quick succession, so their fades appear to overlap. Looped, using setInterval, and staggered, using setTimout, my current code looks like this:

**Markup:**

```
<div class="contents">
    <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidisse deseruisse vim an, mel ad dolores accusata deseruisse. Integre civibus comprehensam his at. Tibique iracundia cu vel, has at luptatum scriptorem. Autem causae omnesque eos te. Mel ad reque noster. Feugiat eleifend maiestatis ut per, maluisset consulatu est ea.</p>
    <p class="content">Sea no cibo praesent. Partem scribentur te eum. Ius in odio mucius, praesent delicatissimi vis ei, mel eu iuvaret honestatis. Cu tantas omnium necessitatibus eam.</p>
    <p class="content">Ut mea ubique putant perfecto. Debet audiam electram vis eu, doctus contentiones ea usu. Cu qui legere possim corrumpit. Quo utinam disputando te, vix decore accusam reprehendunt ex, vis eu mutat delenit. Mel ad nulla vivendum, reprimique voluptatibus et sea.</p>
</div>
```

**Animation:**

```
var updater = function(el){
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
        // Update content here
        $el.fadeTo(500, 1);
    })
};

var reviewTimer = window.setInterval(updateReviews, 3000);

function updateReviews() {
    $.each( $('.content'), function(i, el){
        var $this = $(el);
        setTimeout( function(){
            updater($this)
        }, 0 + ( i * 250 ));
    });
};
```

```js
var updater = function(el){
    var $el = $(el);
    $el.fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
        // Update content here
        $el.fadeTo(500, 1);
    })
};

var reviewTimer = window.setInterval(updateReviews, 3000);

function updateReviews() {
    $.each( $('.content'), function(i, el){
        var $this = $(el);
        setTimeout( function(){
            updater($this)
        }, 0 + ( i * 250 ));
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contents">
    <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidisse deseruisse vim an, mel ad dolores accusata deseruisse. Integre civibus comprehensam his at. Tibique iracundia cu vel, has at luptatum scriptorem. Autem causae omnesque eos te. Mel ad reque noster. Feugiat eleifend maiestatis ut per, maluisset consulatu est ea.</p>
    <p class="content">Sea no cibo praesent. Partem scribentur te eum. Ius in odio mucius, praesent delicatissimi vis ei, mel eu iuvaret honestatis. Cu tantas omnium necessitatibus eam.</p>
    <p class="content">Ut mea ubique putant perfecto. Debet audiam electram vis eu, doctus contentiones ea usu. Cu qui legere possim corrumpit. Quo utinam disputando te, vix decore accusam reprehendunt ex, vis eu mutat delenit. Mel ad nulla vivendum, reprimique voluptatibus et sea.</p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/ajtgeLdq/)

The fiddle doesn't appear to work *too* badly, most of the time, but in my real-world example it suffers from choppy animation (often around 3-10 fps). There's also an automated slider higher up the page, that is probably contributing to the problem.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: don't mix `setTimeout` and jQuery animations - they don't synchronise and events will end up overlapping

Comment: @Alnitak - never knew. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to use jQuery's [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) method for timing effects. I would dump your `updater` method and streamline the `updateReviews` method:

```
var reviewTimer = window.setInterval(updateReviews, 3000);

function updateReviews() {
    $.each( $('.content'), function(i){
        $(this).stop(true, true).delay(i * 250).fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
            // update content here
            $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
        });
    });
};
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajtgeLdq/5/);

Comment: this still suffers from the problem of using JS timers alongside animations.  Instead of using `setInterval` you should arrange for `updateReviews` to be triggered in the completion callback of the final animation step.

Comment: @Alnitak I'm assuming that his use of `setInterval` is purely for testing purposes. Perhaps I have presumed wrong.

Comment: Actually - it wasn't for testing. And I get the feeling I should very ashamed of this.

Comment: Is the set-interval supposed to be long-polling a server for information?

Comment: Not quite. A single JSON file's pulled in on page load, and continually used to update the `.content` html.

Comment: I have added an additional `stop` method which stops the animation and clears the queue before going again. I personally don't see the above code as problematic for this purpose. Perhaps @Alnitak would like to expand on this answer with an answer of his own which can be voted on?

Comment: @Alnitak this page will still be here when you do get the time. I'm sure others would like to hear your solution for the sake of record. :-)

Comment: @shennan - agreed. I'd certainly like to know what Alnitak has in mind. But, for now, this seems to work very well.

Comment: I don't think `.dequeue()` serves a purpose here. That's only when you use it in combination with non synchronous functions that are placed in a `.queue()`. Since it's in the callback of a fade, the object isn't in the effects queue anymore anyway - if it were applicable here at all. Actually, `fadeTo` is synchronous so you don't even need the callback and can just chain it onto the previous one. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ynLnb26/)

Comment: @Shikkediel Hello. I am trying to understand the use of `.dequeue()` in this solution. In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ajtgeLdq/4/ it outputs ["in progress"] for the queue before the dequeue operation and then an empty queue after the operation. What does that even mean? xD I don't get what `.dequeue` is doing there.

Comment: @Fiddle is right. I was using `dequeue` from some boilerplate code which I was using for some asynchronous callbacks. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just `.fadeTo(500, 0, ()=>update content here).fadeTo(500, 1);`

Comment: Check the fiddle a few comments back, you don't really need the callback because `fadeTo` puts the object in the effects queue and makes it synchronous. It's interesting that Shashank's demo reports `inprogress`, I think it is because the callback is also a queue function. But one you don't need to use `.dequeue()` on.

Comment: @Shikkediel The callback is good for the update functionality. See the comment `// Update content here` in OP's code. Ideally that update would happen in the success callback and would be the most clear way to convey it IMO.

Comment: Indeed if you'd like to do stuff in between the fades, the callback could be handy...

Comment: @Shashank Yes, I think the callback should stay as is. It is clear that this is where the OP would like to put his updating logic. Indeed, I think it's the best place for it especially if it is asynchronous and any update problems need to stagger the next effect in the queue.